# Ordering the objects in a particular order - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object of objects. And I want to show the objects and its values in specific order.(not alphabetically)

How can I achieve that with angular? Here it is my sample object

```
var filters = {
    language : { someProperty : "prop1", someOther : "prop2" },
    country : { resumeProp : "prop", resumeProp2 : false },
    destination { resumeProp : "prop", resumeProp2 : false },
};
```

I want to arrange example destination, country and then language.

Comment: How are you going to be displaying the object?

Comment: I will display the keys and the iterate over their values with ng-repeat. But I want to display the keys in a particular order.

Comment: If you want your custom ordering scheme as in your example: destination, country and language, you will need to do that manually. But if you want a lexicographic sort, than you can sort the keys and get the values based on those keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript objects are unordered by definition (see the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), section 4.3.3). The language specification doesn't even guarantee that, if you iterate over the properties of an object twice in succession, they'll come out in the same order the second time.

If you need things to be ordered, use an **array** and the `Array.prototype.sort` method:

```
var filters = [
    { name: "language", order: 2, someProperty : "prop1", someOther : "prop2" },
    { name: "country", order: 1, resumeProp : "prop", resumeProp2 : false },
    { name: "destination", order: 0, resumeProp : "prop", resumeProp2 : false }
];

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.order < b.order)
    return -1;
  else if (a.order > b.order)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}

filters.sort(compare); // destination, country, language
```

If you are coding in ES6 you can use [the **Map** object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is similar to an Object and [guarantees key order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared).

If the original object cannot be modified then

1. create another array with the object's indexes like `var filtersKey = ['destination', 'country', 'language'];`
2. run the **ng-repeat** on that array.
3. get the values from the original object using `filters[value]` where `value` represents each string contained in filtersKey exposed by the ng-repeat.

Comment: I cannot add new objects in my array as you did 'order'.
I want to sort the keys only and get the values accordingly

Comment: @BesaNeziri then you can define a new array like `var filtersKey = ['destination', 'country', 'language']` and run the **ng-repeat** on that array. Then with the `value` you get `filters[value]` from the other array. Directly sorting object keys is impossible.

Comment: @BesaNeziri I updated the answer, please accept it :)